# PHP auto send HTTP auth information

Tags: php, http, authentication, curl

I want from a php file to send the HTTP auth login/password for an auto login without entering them. The two sites ain't at the same server.

edit: i'm trying with curl but can't get it working.

Comment: Seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as this:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://user:pass@http://site.com/')
?>
```

**THIS IS NOT SAFE**, as someone can probably see the password on the headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

u can also specifiy the address as http://login:password@yoursite.com if curl is not mandatory for other tasks

Comment: Thanks man. The second part of your answer really helped me. See my answer below.